# hql query to get map with parent table id as key and list of child objects as value

Tags: java, dictionary, hql

There are two tables parent and child with foreign key relation. Now my requirement is to write hql which return a map with key as parent table id and value as the list of child objects.

Comment: Cool. What's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: i want map which contain key as parent id and value as list of child objects. currently i am thinking something like this
SELECT parentid, COUNT(*) FROM CHILD WHERE parentid IN (SELECT parentid

 from parent) group by parentid;

Comment: Can we do it in single query or it need two queries?

Comment: Why do you select a count if you want a list of children? Why do you have this where clause? It's completely unnecessary since avery parentID in child should either be null or be a valid parent ID. What' do you really want to return. Show me the type of the returned value of the method.

Answer (score 1):

OK. You seem to be completely lost, so here's how I would do it:

```
String hql = 
    "select distinct p from Parent p" // get all the parents
    + " left join fetch p.children";  // with their children
List<Parent> parents = session.createQuery(hql).list();

// now transform this list of parents into a Map
Map<Long, List<Child>> result = new HashMap<Long, List<Child>>(parents.size());
for (Parent parent : parents) {
    result.put(parent.getId(), parent.getChildren());
}
```

Note that I don't really see the point of this map. If you have the list of parents, each containing its children, the map shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks JB this perfect. yes i was really lost. i got the solution.